# Function not searching the txt file when integrated with other functions

Tags: python, function

I have written a program in python. However, the program is not working correctly. It is saving info to a txt file but when I'm searching through the file it says 'not found'. Here is my code:

```
course_info = { '001': ['MS Word', '$10'], '002':['Photoshop', '$180'],
              '003':['Music player','$60'], '004': ['Photo Advance', '$110'],
              }
def menu():
 print("***************************************************\n\t\tDigiSol Online Shop for Software and Applications\n***********************************************\n1. Select this option to view all the available services in our Database\n2. Select this option to search for a service\n3. Select this option to purchase a service\n4. Select this option to view the services you have purchased in the past\n5. Select this option to Exit the program ")
 while True:
    try:
        selected_option = int(input("Please Select Options from above to proceed:"))
    except ValueError: # incase user inputs string values
        print('Its not a number, Choose Options from above')
        continue
    #limiting users input to specific option numbers
    if selected_option < 1 or selected_option > 5:
        print('Invalid Option')
    else:
        break
  return selected_option
def first_option(arg):
    print('\nPlease have a look for services and applications below:\n')                
    for key, value in arg.items():
        print(key, '-', value[0], '---', value[1])
    user_choice = input("\nThank You!\n Enter service ID to purchase or a negative number to exit: ")
    if int(user_choice) < 0:
        exit()
    elif user_choice in arg:
        print('\n' + user_choice + '. ' + arg[user_choice][0] + '   ' + arg[user_choice][1])
        while True:
            permision_to_purchase = input('\nDo you want to buy this service (Y/N)?')
            if permision_to_purchase == 'Y':
                purchase_service(arg, user_choice)
                break
            elif permision_to_purchase == 'N':
                print('Thankyou for reaching out to us\n')
                return
            else:
                print('Please select Y(Yes) or N(No)')
    else:
        print('Entered ID is not valid')

def second_option():
    while True:
        search = input('Enter name of application to see if it is available in our database:')
        searched_service = {}

        for i, j in course_info.items():
            if search in j[0].replace(" ","").lower():
                searched_service[i] = j
        if len(searched_service) == 0:
            print('Course Not Found')
        elif len(searched_service) > 1:
            print('\n',len(searched_service), 'courses have been found:\n' )
            for key, value in searched_service.items():
                print('\nCourse ID: ' + key + '\nCourse Name: '+ value[0]+'\nCourse Price: ' + value[1])
        else:
            print('\n',len(searched_service), 'course have been found:\n' )
            for key, value in searched_service.items():
                print('\nCourse ID: ' + key + '\nCourse Name: '+ value[0]+'\nCourse Price: ' + value[1])  
        while True:
            search_again = input('Do you want to search again (Y/N)?')
            if search_again == 'Y':
                break   # exit inner loop
            elif search_again == 'N':
                return # exit function
            else:
                print('Select Y for Yes or, N for No')

def third_option(arg):
    print('\nThe available coures are listed below:\nCourse ID\t Course Name')                
    for key, value in arg.items():
        print(key, '.', value[0])
    user_choice = input("Please enter course ID to purchase or a negative number to exit: ")
    if int(user_choice) < 0:
        exit()
    elif user_choice in arg:
        print('\n' + user_choice + '. ' + arg[user_choice][0] + '   ' + arg[user_choice][1])
        while True:
            permision_to_purchase = input('\nDo you want to buy this service (Y/N)?')
            if permision_to_purchase == 'Y':
                purchase_service(arg, user_choice)
                break
            elif permision_to_purchase == 'N':
                print('Thankyou for reaching out to us\n')
                return
            else:
                print('Please select Y(Yes) or N(No)')
    else:
        print('Entered ID is not valid')


def fourth_option():
    with open("customer.txt") as searchfile:
        found = False
        while not found:
            name= input('Please enter name to search: ')
            if name == '':
                break  # allow the search-loop to quit on no input
            for line in searchfile:
                if name in line:
                    info = line.split(',')
                    print('Hello ' + info[0] + ' you have purchase the following:\n ' + info[1] + '. ' + info[2])
                    found = True
                    break
                else:
                    print('User hasn''t purchased anything')
                    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        chosen_option = menu()
        if chosen_option == 1:
            first_option(course_info)
        elif chosen_option == 2:
            second_option()
        elif chosen_option == 3:
            third_option(course_info)
        elif chosen_option == 4:
            fourth_option()
        else:
            print('Goodbye')
            break
```

The first and third options are similar and saves info in a text file. I have check the file manually and these functions are working fine. But the fourth option takes name from user and searches from the file. On every search it says 'User not Found' even when the user name is available in the file. Here is the Output:

```
    *******************************************************************
        DigiSol Online Shop for Software and Applications
    *******************************************************************
    1. Select this option to view all the available services in our Database
    2. Select this option to search for a service
    3. Select this option to purchase a service
    4. Select this option to view the services you have purchased in the past
    5. Select this option to Exit the program 
    Please Select Options from above to proceed:3

    The available coures are listed below:
    Course ID    Course Name
    001 . MS Word
    002 . Photoshop
    003 . Music player
    004 . Photo Advance
    Please enter course ID to purchase or a negative number to exit: 001
    
    001. MS Word   $10
    
    Do you want to buy this service (Y/N)?Y
    Please enter your name and your credit card details:
    
    Name: Taha
    Card Number: 229493574
    Please enter a valid card number:
    Card Number: 22
    Please enter a valid card number:
    Card Number: 2294935744
    MM: 90
    YYYY:u875
*******************************************************************
        DigiSol Online Shop for Software and Applications
*******************************************************************

    1. Select this option to view all the available services in our Database
    2. Select this option to search for a service
    3. Select this option to purchase a service
    4. Select this option to view the services you have purchased in the past
    5. Select this option to Exit the program 
    Please Select Options from above to proceed:4
    Please enter name to search: Taha
    User hasnt purchased anything
```

Comment: You need to seek back to the beginning of the file before each `for line in searchfile:` loop. Otherwise it starts from where the last loop stopped.

Comment: In `purchase_service(arg, user_choice)`, you almost certainly want to pass `user_choice`, and not the whole `arg` array.  And you didn't show us `purchase_service`.  Is that where the file gets written?

Comment: @Barmar --  Yes, but that's not the problem here.  It's failing on the first name entered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. This is **way** too much code to show, especially if it's already been organized into functions, and you say that most of it already works. Show the part that doesn't work, plus a *minimum* of code needed *to drive that code and show the problem*. For example, if the problem is that a function doesn't give the right result, then show us *that function*, plus a call to the function *with hard-coded arguments*, plus any globals it uses *directly set to the values that they need to have* to cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking the first line in the file. When you read the line, you check if it has a matching customer name. If it matches you break out of the loop inner loop. If it doesn't match, you print the "User hasn't purchased anything" message and return from the function, which ends both loops.

You have to keep looping through the file. You shouldn't break out when you find a match, since they might have multiple purchases. At the end, check the `found` variable to determine whether to say that they didn't purchase anything. There's no need for the `while not found:` loop. And you shouldn't ask for the name in the loop; use separate calls for different customers.

```
def fourth_option():
    name= input('Please enter name to search: ')
    if name == '':
        return  # allow the search-loop to quit on no input
    with open("customer.txt") as searchfile:
        found = False
        for line in searchfile:
            customer, courseid, coursename = line.strip().split(',')
            if customer == name:
                print('Hello ' + customer + ' you have purchase the following:\n ' + courseid + '. ' + coursename)
                found = True
        if not found:
            print("User hasn't purchased anything")
```